# Make a call to oauth/token using my custom login controller

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am implementing oauth2 with spring-security using springboot2.

directly when I make a call to oauth/token I am able to get results... works fine.

I need to make it work the same from my custom login controller, from where I can redirect the request to oauth/token for generating tokens. The reason for this is that I need to store access token and login times in the database.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = { RequestMethod.OPTIONS, RequestMethod.POST })
public Object login(HttpServletRequest  request, HttpServletResponse     
            response, @RequestParam Map<String, String> params) {

//Here I want to make a call to oauth/token.

    }
```

Please help in this regard. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.set("Authorization", "YOUR_BASIC");
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>("", headers);
    String authURL = "YOUR_URL/oauth/token?grant_type=YOUR_GRANT_TYPE&username=" + YOUR_USERNAME + "&password=YOUR_PASSWORD&scope=ui";
    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(authURL, entity, String.class);
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(responseEntity.getBody());
    jsonObj.get("access_token").toString();
```

Dependency:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20180130</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Please don't just post code as an answer, explain what it does and why it solves the problem of the question.

Comment: This is how our custom method calls the auth-server. And here we can log the token / time, etc.